# Efficient way to multiply numpy arrays by row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 3 different numpy arrays. For example:

```
arr1 = array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

arr2 = array([[1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.77519575, 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
   [0.77519575, 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])

arr3 = array([[0.08333333, 0.06666667, 0.13333333, 0.21428571, 0.08571429,
    0.17241379, 0.        , 0.14285714, 0.06896552, 0.04166667],
   [0.16666667, 0.        , 0.33333333, 0.21428571, 0.08571429,
    0.        , 0.14285714, 0.14285714, 0.17241379, 0.08333333],
   [0.125     , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.02857143,
    0.        , 0.03571429, 0.10714286, 0.13793103, 0.125     ],
   [0.        , 0.06666667, 0.13333333, 0.14285714, 0.14285714,
    0.        , 0.03571429, 0.03571429, 0.        , 0.04166667],
   [0.16666667, 0.13333333, 0.26666667, 0.35714286, 0.        ,
    0.13793103, 0.07142857, 0.14285714, 0.13793103, 0.16666667],
   [0.20833333, 0.06666667, 0.2       , 0.        , 0.02857143,
    0.10344828, 0.17857143, 0.14285714, 0.03448276, 0.20833333],
   [0.20833333, 0.1       , 0.26666667, 0.07142857, 0.08571429,
    0.17241379, 0.07142857, 0.14285714, 0.        , 0.04166667],
   [0.125     , 0.1       , 0.26666667, 0.21428571, 0.08571429,
    0.        , 0.17857143, 0.        , 0.13793103, 0.125     ],
   [0.125     , 0.16666667, 0.2       , 0.07142857, 0.        ,
    0.17241379, 0.17857143, 0.07142857, 0.06896552, 0.125     ],
   [0.08333333, 0.16666667, 0.26666667, 0.28571429, 0.02857143,
    0.17241379, 0.10714286, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])
```

What I need to do is loop through each row and get each row from `arr1` and `arr3` and multiply them with `arr2` and then sum the elements and store that result in a dictionary. To make things more clear, this is what I am doing:

```
results_dict = {}
for i,idx in tqdm(enumerate(my_index)):
    my_list = arr1[i]
    my_weights = arr3[i]
    results_dict[idx] = dict(enumerate(np.sum(my_list * arr2 * my_weights, axis = 0).flatten(), 1))
```

This works for me, however the sizes of these arrays can get quite large, so I am trying to see if there is a more efficient way to do this, and perhaps use built-in numpy functions to eliminate the loop. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you post a minimal example with smaller arrays (e.g. 3x3) and the desired output? It's kind of hard to see what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You could have made things clearer by showing some, if not all of the results.  Anyways getting rid of the undefined `tqdm` bit, here's what I get:

```
In [133]: results_dict
Out[133]: 
{0: {1: 0.1479329732493475,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.13333333,
  4: 0.3803990816777325,
  5: 0.08571429,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.06896552,
  10: 0.0},
 1: {1: 0.2958659642506525,
 ...
```

So it's a dict of dicts, with individual numeric values.  You cannot get rid of the loops with `numpy` this way.

for one `i` value the calculation is:

```
In [135]: i = 0
     ...: np.sum(arr1[i] * arr2 * arr3[i], axis=0)
Out[135]: 
array([0.14793297, 0.        , 0.13333333, 0.38039908, 0.08571429,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.06896552, 0.        ])
```

And yes, as suggested with the other answer we can calculate these values for all "rows" with one expression, `einsum` or `dot` or `matmul`.  But there's still the question creating the dicts.  And I suspect that's the big time consumer here.

Changing the dicts to list:

```
In [136]: alist = []
     ...: for i in range(arr1.shape[0]):
     ...:     my_list = arr1[i]
     ...:     my_weights = arr3[i]
     ...:     alist.append(np.sum(my_list * arr2 * my_weights, axis=0))
     ...: 
In [137]: alist
Out[137]: 
[array([0.14793297, 0.        , 0.13333333, 0.38039908, 0.08571429,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.06896552, 0.        ]),
...
        0.        , 0.10714286, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ])]
```

which can be turned into a (10,10) array with:

```
In [138]: np.array(alist)
Out[138]: 
array([[0.14793297, 0.        , 0.13333333, 0.38039908, 0.08571429,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.06896552, 0.        ],
...
       [0.14793297, 0.        , 0.26666667, 0.50719879, 0.02857143,
        0.        , 0.10714286, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])
```

That `np.sum(arr1[i] * arr2 * arr3[i], axis=0)` can be written with `einsum` as:

```
In [143]: np.einsum("j,kj,j->j", arr1[i], arr2, arr3[i])
Out[143]: 
array([0.14793297, 0.        , 0.13333333, 0.38039908, 0.08571429,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.06896552, 0.        ])
```

and generalized to all rows (`i`):

```
In [144]: np.einsum("ij,kj,ij->ij", arr1, arr2, arr3)
```

and since we are only summing on `k`, that can be written just as simply as

```
arr1 * arr2.sum(axis=0) * arr3
```

In other words, just reduce `arr2` to a (10,) array, and multiply.  There's nothing fancy here.

It may help to note that while `arr1` is (m,n), `arr1[i]` is (n,). Same for `arr3`.  With `arr2` of shape (k,n), these `broadcast` to (1,n), with the result (k,n).  Sum on the `k`, and you are left with (n,) shape.  You aren't summing on the rows or columns of `arr1` or `arr3`, just on the rows of `arr2`.

My iterative list version of your dicts can be written as:

```
In [150]: alist = []
     ...: arr2sum = arr2.sum(axis=0)
     ...: for i in range(arr1.shape[0]):
     ...:     alist.append(arr1[i] * arr2sum * arr3[i])
     ...: x = np.array(alist)
```

and your `dict` code becomes:

```
results_dict[idx] = dict(enumerate(np.sum(my_list * arr2sum * my_weights, 1))
```